# Can I import 1 Kubernetes Cluster on 2 different Rancher Instances

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

Can anyone let me know if we can import one K8s cluster on 2 different Rancher instances.

Comment: Could you elaborate your question? What you want to import and from where? Your local cluster, Cloud cluster (GKE, AKS, EKS)? You want to import configuration or your application?

Answer (score 0):

**Answer: No**

It's not possible to manage a single k8s cluster using two different Rancher management instances.

This requirement has never been part of the initial design.